# Executing arbitrary code in MVVMCross View when ViewModel changes

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I was wondering about the best way to execute code (that doesn't bind a control's value to the value in the view model) when a view model value changes.

Or, perhaps I'm just approaching this completely wrong way :)  What I'd like to do is use a value from the view model in code similar to the following (from http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/play_a_video_using_avplayer/):

```
_asset = AVAsset.FromUrl (NSUrl.FromFilename (VALUE_FROM_VIEW_MODEL));
_playerItem = new AVPlayerItem (_asset);
_player = new AVPlayer (_playerItem);

_playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.FromPlayer (_player);
_playerLayer.Frame = View.Frame;
View.Layer.AddSublayer (_playerLayer);
_player.Play ();
```

Where the actual video being played is determined by a value on the view model.

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: May be the MvvmCross Messenger can help you? https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger

Comment: Thanks, that's the route I've ended up going but not sure of its elegance :)